# QT qScriptConnect is not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtscript

```
QScriptEngine eng;
QScriptEngineDebugger debugger;
debugger.attachTo(&eng);
QScriptValue consoleObj =  eng.newQObject(this);
eng.globalObject().setProperty("asd", consoleObj);
QScriptValue handler= eng.evaluate("(function(text) { asd.log('text was changed to '+text); })");
QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
qScriptConnect(edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), QScriptValue(), handler);
edit->show();
```

`qScriptConnect(edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), QScriptValue(), handler)` is not working, but when i am using `handler.call(QScriptValue(),args)` it works well;

```
QScriptValueList args;
args << 3;
handler.call(QScriptValue(),args);
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
      Q_INVOKABLE void log(QString msg);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<qscriptengine.h>
#include<qscriptenginedebugger.h>
#include<qlineedit.h>
#include<qdebug.h>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QScriptEngine eng;
    QScriptEngineDebugger debugger;
    debugger.attachTo(&eng);
    QScriptValue consoleObj =  eng.newQObject(this);
    eng.globalObject().setProperty("asd", consoleObj);
    QScriptValue handler= eng.evaluate("(function(text) { asd.log('text was changed to '+text); })");
    QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
    qDebug()<<qScriptConnect(edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), QScriptValue(), handler);
    edit->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::log(QString msg)
{
    qDebug() << "jsConsole: "<< msg;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean of *is not working*? that description is very ambiguous

Comment: qScriptConnect returns true but when line edit's text changes nothing happens.. doesn't works that slot

Comment: You have to created a q_invokable  function called log(Qstring)..

Comment: Just add q_invokable void log(Qstring) function

Comment: I am calling that c++ function from js... Log function  prints to application out put console  using qdebug

Comment: But it doesn't work for me

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WDiSnXl.jpg

Comment: https://imgur.com/XifcF5l

Comment: updated question

Comment: That's what I meant with MCVE, the code you showed initially did not show the cause of the error.

Comment: now i can understand that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable created in a method that is not created in the heap is deleted when it finishes executing the method, in your case the `QScriptEngine` is created in the constructor reason why it is eliminated, and all the script depends on it. The solution is simple, make the `QScriptEngine` member of the class:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScriptEngine>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    Q_INVOKABLE void log(const QString & text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QScriptEngine eng; // member
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QScriptEngine>
#include <QScriptEngineDebugger>

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QScriptEngineDebugger debugger;
    debugger.attachTo(&eng);
    QScriptValue consoleObj =  eng.newQObject(this);
    eng.globalObject().setProperty("asd", consoleObj);
    QScriptValue handler= eng.evaluate("(function(text) { asd.log('text was changed to '+text); })");
    QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);
    qScriptConnect(edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), QScriptValue(), handler);
    edit->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::log(const QString &text)
{
    qDebug()<< text;
}
```